# Is there .Net 4 commonly used namespaces poster?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for .Net 4 commonly used namespaces poster, like [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7B645F3A-6D22-4548-A0D8-C2A27E1917F8) one available for .NET 3.5. So far I've managed to find only .NET Framework 4.0  [important Namespaces and Types](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A8A715-7695-493C-8CFA-8E0C23A4BE1D/098-115952-NETFX4-Poster.pdf) poster, but is there something more detailed?

Answer (score 3):

There is also this one, but I believe it's more ancient: http://brad_abrams.members.winisp.net/Projects/PDC2008/PDC2008-NETFX4.pdf

Another link to the same file: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/2/3/923d72fb-0076-49b6-96c4-aac1c255a60e/PDC2008-NETFX4.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There would have to be a whole family of such posters.  Namespaces and classes which are "commonly used" in ASP.NET e-commerce applications would probably never appear in XNA game development.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick app to search a folder (and its subfolders) for assemblies and use reflection to capture their namespaces and classes.  The app outputs a sorted list of namespaces and their classes.  I aimed the app at the folder containing the .Net 4.0 assemblies (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0) to get a list of all the .Net 4.0 namespaces and classes.  It is not a pretty poster, just a list.

The list is much too long to post here.  Therefore, I will post the code for my app and let you run it on your own on whatever files your like.  Note that it currently crunches the .Net 4.0 files - you will have to modify for whatever files you desire.

```
    internal class ClassInfo
{
    public ClassInfo(string namespaceName, string className)
    {
        NamespaceName = namespaceName;
        ClassName = className;
    }

    public string NamespaceName { get; private set; }
    public string ClassName { get; private set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        IList<ClassInfo> _classes = new List<ClassInfo>();
        //DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0");

        ProcessFolder(folder, _classes);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("*************** NAMESPACES ***************");
        Console.WriteLine();
        PrintNamespaces(_classes);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("*************** NAMESPACES/CLASSES ***************");
        Console.WriteLine();
        PrintClassesByNamespaces(_classes);
    }

    private static void PrintNamespaces(IList<ClassInfo> classes)
    {
        var namespaces = (from c in classes
                          orderby c.NamespaceName
                          select c.NamespaceName).Distinct();

        foreach (string s in namespaces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    private static void PrintClassesByNamespaces(IList<ClassInfo> classes)
    {
        var namespaces = (from c in classes
                          orderby c.NamespaceName
                          select c.NamespaceName).Distinct();

        foreach (string s in namespaces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            var namespaceClasses = (from c in classes
                                    where c.NamespaceName == s
                                    orderby c.ClassName
                                    select c.ClassName).Distinct();

            foreach (string className in namespaceClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"   {className}");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessFolder(DirectoryInfo directory, IList<ClassInfo> classes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"folder: {directory.FullName}");

        foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles("*.dll"))
        {
            ProcessAssembly(directory, f.FullName, classes);
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            ProcessFolder(d, classes);
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessAssembly(DirectoryInfo directory, string fileName, IList<ClassInfo> classes)
    {
        Assembly assembly;

        try
        {
            assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);

            foreach (var t in assembly.DefinedTypes)
            {
                classes.Add(new ClassInfo(t.Namespace, t.Name));
                Console.WriteLine($"{t.Namespace} - {t.Name}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"something wrong loading {fileName} - {ex.Message}");
        }
    }        
}
```